# Tesseract on iOS - bad results

Tags: ios, tesseract

After spending over 10 hours to compile tesseract using libc++ so it works with OpenCV, I've got issue getting any meaningful results. I'm trying to use it for digit recognition, the image data I'm passing is a small square (50x50) image with either one or no digits in it.

I've tried using both eng and equ tessdata (from google code), the results are different but both get guess 0 digits. Using eng data I get **'4\n\n'** or **'\n\n'** as a result most of the time (even when there's no digit in the image), with confidence anywhere from 1 to 99.
Using equ data I get **'\n\n'** with confidence 0-4.

I also tried binarizing the image and the results are more or less the same, I don't think there's a need for it though since images are filtered pretty good.

I'm assuming that there's something wrong since the images are pretty easy to recognize compared to even simplest of the example images.

Here's the code:

**Initialization:**

```
    _tess = new TessBaseAPI();
    _tess->Init([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "eng");
    _tess->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
    _tess->SetVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
```

**Recognition:**

```
char *text = _tess->TesseractRect(imageData, (int)bytes_per_pixel, (int)bytes_per_line, 0, 0, (int)imageSize.width, (int)imageSize.height);
```

I'm getting no errors. TESSDATA_PREFIX is set properly and I've tried different methods for recognition. imageData looks ok when inspected.

Here are some sample images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPAYR.jpg

Should this work with the regular training data?

Any help is appreciated, my first time trying tessarect out and I could have missed something.

**EDIT:**

I've found this:

```
    _tess->SetPageSegMode(PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
```

I'm assuming it must be used in this situation, tried it but got the same results.

Comment: Those are extremely low resolution images. Try rescan it at 300 DPI and see if you get better results.

Comment: They are not scanned, and the original image that I extract the squares from is pretty big. I'm sizing it down for pre-processing (somewhat complex). I'll try getting bigger images to this step if it doesn't effect performance too much for the pre-processing part if you think it should make difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think Tesseract is a bit overkill for this stuff. You would be better off with a simple neural network, trained explicitly for your images. At my company, recently we were trying to use Tesseract on iOS for an OCR task (scanning utility bills with the camera), but it was too slow and inaccurate for our purposes (scanning took more than 30 seconds on an iPhone 4 at a tremendously low FPS). At the end, I trained a neural-network specifically for our target font, and this solution not only beat Tesseract (it could scan stuff flawlessly even on an iPhone 3Gs), but also a commercial ABBYY OCR engine, which we were given a sample from the company. 
[This course's](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) material would be a good start in machine learning.

Comment: I agree on the overkill part. The thing is that this is not a commercial project and I don't want to spend too much time on this, so I tried going with the solution that should take the least time.

As for the speed I don't think it would be an issue, the images are rather small and even right now the code that doesn't give good results runs pretty fast (few seconds). Either way I'll be demoing it on iPhone 5 and performances are not expected to be top-notch.